# How to save a type of a pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Function1 can be called with any type T which will be converted to (void*) to be able to add to the list but with this I lose the original pointer type (I need t store tham in one linkedlist because I cannot create one for every possible type). So somehow I need to save the type of the pointer as well. I know that it cant be done using c++. Can anyone suggest an alternative solution?

```
class MyClass
{

    template<class T>
    void function1(T* arg1)
    {
        myList.add((void*)arg);
    }

    void function2()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
        {
            myList.get(i);
            //restore the original pointer type
        }
    }

    STLinkedlist<void*> myList;
}
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the type information afterwards?

Comment: Stop trying to make C++ be like Java.

Comment: I will restore the original pointer type like (original_pointer_type)myList.get(i);

Comment: @DarlekSupreme How will you handle many types stored in one list?

Comment: "I know that it cant be done using c++" means you are looking for an answer like "Use Java!" or "Use C#!", am I right?

Comment: The best solution is to use the right language to the right problem. It may be Java, Python or Ruby. C++ disallow it for a good reason. f you need it, you need another language

Comment: To get a more useful answer other than "don't do this", you are going to have to put more detail into why you want to do this. Eg show you you want to use MyClass, describe the problem you are trying to solve, and/or describe what you would do if you did it in another language.

Comment: @sammy if you're going to language hop because language A doesn't do what language B could, you're not doing it right. First thing you do is ask yourself (or stackoverflow.com) *why* language A doesn't have it, and then why you *think* you need it, and finally how you can do it differently.

Comment: @David Miani: Good point +1. I'd like to add: What kind of objects will be in that list? They must have something in common. It doesn't make sense to make a list of "a coffee cup", "an elephant", and "Love". So what is higher abstraction level, i.e. base class, of these objects in your list?

Comment: @DarlekSupreme: +1. I like this question because it might help others to solve similar problems. And for beginners for example this might be a common challenge.

Comment: @Tobi One issue is that the question does not the state the actual problem: it only states the problem with the presumed solution to the actual problem. Since the solution the problem with the presumed solution might be to get rid of the presumed solution and use a better one (which cannot be stated without knowing the actual problem), I don't think this will be good help to many people.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I so agree with you. Still, others might think of something similar and should be pointed in the right direction as well. I find that especially in C++ it sometimes is difficult to spot the real problem.

Comment: @Tobi Erm, the real problem is whatever leads you to think "I'll solve **that** with a vector of `void*`". If you don't know that, it's not C++'s fault...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way to handle these kinds of problems is  by using a public interface, in C++ this is done through inheritance. This can be a drag, especially in constrained situations, where a full class/interface hierarchy would provide too much code/runtime overhead.

In comes [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html#variant.intro), which allows you to use the same object to store different types. If you need even more freedom, use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html#idp23550912). For a comparison, see e.g. [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any).

At the end of the day (or better: rather sooner than later), I'd try to do things differently so you don't have this problem. It may well be worth it in the end.

Comment: I'll just note that the more "freedom" you get in the storage, the less freedom you have in the usage afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

If you lost the type info by going void* it is just gone. You can not just restore it.

So you either must store extra information along with the pointer, then use branching code to cast it back, or rather drive design to avoid the loss.

Your case is pretty suspicious that you do not what you really want.

A more usual case is that you want a polymorphic collection. That doesn't store any kind of pointers but those belonging to the same hierarchy. Collection has Base* pointers, and you can use the objects through Base's interface, all calling the proper virtual function without programmer's  interaction.  And if you really need to cast to the original type you can do it via dynamic_cast safely.  Or add some type info support in the base interface.

Answer (score 3):

> Function1 can be called with any type T which will be converted to (void*) to be able to add to the list but with this I lose the original pointer type (I need t store tham in one linkedlist because I cannot create one for every possible type).

You're having [the XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). The solution is not to decay your pointers to void* and store type information.

You simply *can* create a type for every possible type - you create a template type. You need to define an abstract interface for your "type for every object", then define a template class implementing this interface, that is particularized by type. Finally, you create your custom-type instance on your type of pointer received and store them by base class pointer (where the base class is your interface definition).

All that said, you (normally) shouldn't need to implement this at all, because the functionality is already implemented in boost::any or boost::variant (you will have to choose one of them).

Comment: will this work with visual studio 2012 and windows store apps?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Windows store apps but it's C++ (boost library); as far as I know it is supported with Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

### General

Take into consideration, that if you want to store different objects inside a `std::vector<void *>`, mostly likely your application has a *bad design*. In this case, I'd think, *whether it is really necessary* to do it (or how can it be done in another way), rather than searching for the solution, *how* to do it.

However, there are no fully [*evil*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/defn-evil.html) things in C++ (nor in any other language), so if you are absolutely certain, that this is the only solution, here are three possible ways to solve your problem.

### Option 1

If you store only pointers to simple types, store the original type along with the pointer by an enum value or simply a string.

```
enum DataType
{
    intType,
    floatType,
    doubleType
};

std::vector<std::pair<void *, DataType>> myData;
```

### Option 2

If you store mixed data (classes and simple types), wrap your data in some kind of class.

```
class BaseData 
{ 
public:
    virtual ~BaseData() { }
};

class IntData : public BaseData
{
public:
    int myData;
};

std::vector<BaseData *> myData;
```

Later, you'll be able to check the type of your data using `dynamic_cast`.

### Option 3

If you store only classes, store them simply as a pointer to their base class and `dynamic_cast` your way out.

Comment: Actual type in a program I inherited: `VectorClass<DiscreteDistribution<AITriggerTypeClass *>>` . Have fun putting that much info into an enum.

Comment: But using option 1 I need to extend the enum manually every time I want to use a new type. But I like the idea I only need something similar like the enum but which can be extended dinamically.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` doesn't check any types. It just blindly throws you into the land of implementation-defined or undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DCoder Well, that depends on what kind of data you want to store. For instance, I had to store tokens or mathematical expression elements and enum did very well in that case. If the first option is unacceptable, you can always choose the second one. Actually, if you store only classes, you can simply `dynamic_cast` your way out, without need for a wrapper.

Comment: @DarlekSupreme Then Option 2 is what you seek for. C++ **does not** have as extended reflection capabilities as Java or C# does, so if you have no other option, simply use these languages instead of C++. I can think of no other options, that listed previously.

Comment: How do you know this is a use case for reflection if there is no use case detailed in the question? (relevant: http://www.antiifcampaign.com/)

Comment: You need to make `BaseData` a polymorphic class for `dynamic_cast` to work.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't. That's why I wrote three different options for three different use cases. About the polymorphic class, you're right, I fixed that. Now should be OK.

Comment: I don't get the eager downvotes either. And reiterpret_cast is fully defined to round-trip if you make sure to cast bach to the original type. So the described way works. Different question whether it aligns with the aim or not, but the question was not providing enough info on that. And the answer was edited, please reconsider and undo the downvotes

Comment: @BalogPal I downvoted because the suggested use of `reinterpret_cast` (since edited out) was not defined at all ("(...) check the type of your data using (...)"). The described way did not work (check edit history if you want). And FWIW to go between `void*` and other pointer types, you can use `static_cast` just fine. Put simply, `reinterpret_cast` has no reason to be part of this discussion.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes For the whole time I had `dynamic_cast` in mind, which may work as a replacement for C#'s `as` operator. I've simply mistaken it with `reinterpret_cast`. I know, that using `dynamic_cast` that way is *evil*, but it is perfectly valid in terms of C++ standard (if used with classes - as I suggested in my further edits).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: it's a long-standing stalled debate really :). void* -> T* can be done with either static or reinterpret cast with the same effect. AAMOF you can arrange reinterpret_cast effect with just implicit+static_cast that way. For that reason many mentors suggest using reinterpret_cast for that particular case to stand out.   As for DV history, we can leave it there, just make the current status reflected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `boost::any` to store any type in your list instead of use `void*`. It's not exactly what you want but I don't think you can restore the type in run time (as Kerrek said, it's not Java).

```
class MyClass
{

   template<class T>
   void function1(T arg1)
   {
      myList.add(arg);
   }

   template<class T>
   T get(int i)
   {
      return boost::any_cast<T>(myList.get(i));
   }

   STLinkedlist<boost::any> myList;
};
```